# How to set the child control size inside ellipse when resize wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am creating a user control which has a shape (a curved line) inside a circle. I used ellipse control to create the circle.how to keep the size of the shape inside the ellipse when resize?

Comment: have you tried putting the ellipse in a ViewBox?

Comment: yes, but the shape inside the circle is an another user control. i want to add that too to create my new usercontrol. but i can add only one child intto the viewbox.

Comment: show us the xaml than, it's impossible like this to tell what is going on

Comment: I'm confident you can get what you're after a number of ways (Shoving both the Ellipse and 'shape' inside a canvas / a grid / a viewbox then managing the size of the container instead of the two separate elements, for example), but I'd still like to see some xaml.

Comment: i just want to create a circle with a line inside it.

Comment: <Ellipse Height="80" Width="80" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding Background , FallbackValue=Plum}"></Ellipse>. Inside this circle i want to create a curved line which should fit to this circle when resize the control.

Comment: thanks  @Logan, i've added those two controls inside a canvas and i put the canvas in the Viewbox and it woks fine. Now, the problem is when i set the background color of the usercontrol, the color of the viewbox or panel is only changing. how to change the color inside the circle?

Comment: thanks @Nikola.Lukovic,

Comment: If I were you, i'd shove this ellipse and line inside your user control's Template. So in <UserControl.Template><ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl"> HERE </ControlTemplate> </UserControl.Template>. Then you can just tell the Ellipse and Line's 'Fill' property to be {TemplateBinding Background} and they will just be whatever colour you tell the UserControl to be.